# How to random choose several value from a list based on the value from other list?

Tags: python, list, max

I have two lists and one number. list `val` is a list of numerical values(can have repeated value),

```
val = [3,2,5,6,1,6]
```

list `pair` is list of paired values(cannot have repeated value)

```
pair = [(1,3),(3,2),(7,3),(6,5),(3,4),(5,7)]
```

both list have same length, i.e., `len(val) = len(pair)`. The number is a numeric value, say `num=4`.

The task is to find whether is there any value in list `val` are larger or equal to `num`, if so, find out all the maximum value and random choose one value with same index from `pair`. For the above example, the result should random choose a value from `(6,5)` or `(5,7)`. I can write a long code with several function to finish this job. I wonder is there any concise way to do this?

Comment: Please post what you have tried, and where are you stuck? this is not a code writing service.

Comment: Jack, I'm your teacher! I told you don't ask the internet without any own effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
num = 4
val = [3,2,5,6,1,6]
pair = [(1,3),(3,2),(7,3),(6,5),(3,4),(5,7)]

import random
print random.choice([random.choice(pair[v]) for v in range(len(val)) if val[v] == max(val)])
```